# PVRGeoPOD add-on is not found from preference after installation

Tags: add-on

I downloaded the add-on, PVRGeoPOD (Mac) from [here](https://www.imgtec.com/developers/powervr-sdk-tools/pvrgeopod/). Then I double-clicked the downloaded .pkg to install on my Mac.  But when I want to activate it from the Preferences in Blender, I can't find the add-on.  Could anyone tell me how to install the add-on please?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cgchan.com/static/doc/sceneskies/1.1/installation.html
That's how to install an addon. It seems like software that has a business behind it, and this question is toward that software. I would ask them how to install.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add PVRGeoPod like this:

1. create a .zip file containing PVRGeoPOD, libPVRGeoPOD.dylib, PVRGeoPODScript.py. I named it PVRGeoPod.zip.
2. open Blender, go to preferences > Add-ons > "Install..."
3. select the new zip file
4. it installed the add on under ~/Library/Application Support/Blender/...